# How to enable VNC in VM in KVM when the KVM server doesn't have a GUI?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, kvm, libvirt

Can someone tell me how to enable the VNC in VM which is being created using virt-install on KVM hypervisor?

My server **doesn't have a GUI** so I used to run the following command to spin up a VM:

```
virt-install \
--name centos6 \
--ram 1024 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/centos6.img,bus=virtio,size=30 \
--vcpus 1 \
--os-type linux \
--os-variant rhel6 \
--network bridge=br0 \
--graphics none \
--location 'http://mirror.i3d.net/pub/centos/6/os/x86_64/' \
--extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

Now I want to install GUI on the VM(centos6) and install VNC, can someone tell me how to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer on this link though it is implemented on ubuntu but same can be replicated for other distribution : https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-gnome-vnc-headless-server